# Making st_buffer and visualizing it in QGIS?

Tags: postgis

so i have a road and i need to make a buffer of 30 meters around it. It is a road made out of few segments.
so i was thinking:

```
    SELECT a.ref St_buffer(a.geom,30)
FROM osm_roads a
WHERE a.ref='A306'
```

Am i missing something?

Do i have to do a union on the segments, because i need the road as a whole?

How do i do that?

How can i visualise it in qgis via PostGIS?

Comment: To visualize use qgis db manager to connect to postgres and run queries. then they can be added to qgis. test the queries to see if you need union or not.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] which emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: You missed a comma, this is a syntax error: SELECT a.ref, St_buffer(a.geom,30)
FROM osm_roads a WHERE a.ref='A306'